# SOAP WS - a single client for multiple different installations of the same service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

**Motivation**

I'm building a command-line utility which allows the user to manipulate user accounts on a server from a remote computer. For this purpose, the server provides a SOAP WS API.

**The question**

If I generate the client code from the WSDL file with the wsimport tool, the application becomes fixed to a single server installation (the IP address of the server is fixed in the code on multiple places).

I would need the application to allow the user to work with any server installation. They should only be asked for the IP address of the target server at application start-up.

What is the best/correct way to achieve this?

Comment: place url in database or .perperties file and then let user select the ip and port.then in generated proxy file read from db or .properties file. i myself have a similar scenario and put in .properies file.

Comment: The problem is that the stub classes I managed to generate with the wsimport tool do not take the IP of the server as a parameter. On the contrary, it is fixed in there on multiple places (a String literal in the code). How do I generate stubs that support the scenario?

Comment: i will send you my code

Comment: Please send it to the email address associated with my SO account. Thank you very much.

Comment: dusan.rychnovsky@gmail.com, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After generating wsdl proxy. the is a file with annotation 
@WebServiceClient.

I generate proxy for following url (wsdl location)

```
http://192.168.1.185:10530/service?wsdl
```

In constructor of class you can pass desired url that set by setter string or file or any data read from database.

looking for file with annotation @WebServiceClient(that contain getBasicHttpBinding method)
then add following. before using this set the desired url and call getBasichttpBinding....

```
private static String serviceUrl = "";

public static void setUrl(String url){
    serviceUrl = url;
}

public ServiceClient(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public ServiceClient() {
    super(serviceUrl, new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "Service"));
}
```